# KeyError: 'One or more row labels was not found' >> lookup python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lookup, lookup-tables

I have a problem with my script which generates KeyError: 'One or more row labels was not found'

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Destcode' : ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'],
                     'City A' : ['Available','Available','Available','Available','Not Available','Not Available','Available'],
                     'City B' : ['Not Available','Available','Not Available','Available','Not Available','Not Available','Available'],
                     'City C' : ['Available','Available','Not Available','Available','Not Available','Available','Available']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Destcode' : ['C','F','G','D','E'],
                     'Origin' : ['City A','City C','City A','City B','City D']})
```

so, i have 2 DataFrame.

DataFrame 1

```
df1
   Destcode       City A         City B         City C
0     A       Available      Not Available   Available
1     B       Available      Available       Available
2     C       Available      Not Available   Not Available
3     D       Available      Available       Available
4     E       Not Available  Not Available   Not Available
5     F       Not Available  Not Available   Available
6     G       Available      Available       Available
```

DataFrame 2

```
df2
    Destcode    Origin
0      C        City A
1      F        City C
2      G        City A
3      D        City B
4      E        City D
```

And I run this script

```
df2['Cek Available'] = df1.set_index('Destcode').lookup(df2.Destcode, df2.Origin)
```

And I get an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irrDy.png)

I know the problem is in Origin City D which is not in DataFrame df1.

How do you do that if the data you are looking for does not exist, it will return the value "Not Available"?
Please help me to solve this problem

```
   Destcode   Origin    Cek Available
0      C      City A          ?
1      F      City C          ?
2      G      City A          ?
3      D      City B          ?
4      E      City D          ?
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Note that 'lookup` is deprecated in 1.2.0

Comment: Can you help me to write a script that can help me solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try/except` and a `for` loop:

```
cek = []
df1 = df1.set_index('Destcode')
for c, o in zip(df2['Destcode'], df2['Origin']):
    try:
        x = df1.loc[c,o]
    except:
        x = np.nan

    cek.append(x)

df2['Cek Available'] = cek
```

Output:

```
  Destcode  Origin Cek Available
0        C  City A     Available
1        F  City C     Available
2        G  City A     Available
3        D  City B     Available
4        E  City D           NaN
```

Comment: perfect, except : x = 'Not Available' will return the value I want.
Thanks

Comment: May I ask?
What is the meaning of "for c, o"
What is the function?

Answer (score 0):

Data is usually easier to work with when it's in [tidy data format](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html).  Melt `df1` and join.

```
df3 = df1.melt(id_vars="Destcode", var_name="Origin")
df2.merge(df3, on=["Destcode", "Origin"], how="left")
```

results in

```
  Destcode  Origin      value
0        C  City A  Available
1        F  City C  Available
2        G  City A  Available
3        D  City B  Available
4        E  City D        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `get` and `melt`:

```
x = df1.melt(id_vars='Destcode', var_name='Origin').set_index(['Destcode', 'Origin']).squeeze()
df2['Cek Available'] = df2.apply(lambda y: x.get(tuple(y), np.nan), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
  Destcode  Origin Cek Available
0        C  City A     Available
1        F  City C     Available
2        G  City A     Available
3        D  City B     Available
4        E  City D           NaN
>>>
```